# Grep timestamp for last 24 hours in bash

Tags: linux, bash, grep, design-patterns

I have a log file, which has data in the following format

```
[1360643407] SERVICE NOTIFICATION: qreda;demo-jms2;OutConnectorResponse-SPONSORED-SMS;CRITICAL;notify-service-by-email;CRITICAL ConsumerCount=0

[1360643487] SERVICE NOTIFICATION: qreda;demo-jms2;OutConnectorResponse-OPT-IN-OUT;CRITICAL;notify-service-by-email;CRITICAL ConsumerCount=0
```

I want to grep this file to show logs for last 24 hours. Here date is showing as timestamp. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `awk` for this:

```
awk 'BEGIN {now=systime()} {then=strtonum(gensub(/\[|\]/,"","g",$1)); if(now-86400<=then) print}'
```